# Not able to access storage in Content Scripts in Chrome Extension Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I tried to access information stored in `chrome.storage.session` in my content script, but the browser keeps informing me that "Access to storage is not allowed from this context" even though I enabled "storage" in `manifest.json`

After fetching some data in my background script, I store the received

```
chrome.storage.session.set({"data": data});
```

However, when I try to access it in my content script by running the following line:

```
chrome.storage.session.get(["data"],function(data){console.log(data)})
```

I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'session')
```

However, when I run the exact same command in my background script, I was able to retrieve the data.

I also made sure I enabled "storage" permission in my `manifest.json`. Why is this happening?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I think you have to set access level. See this post on google groups [link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/il2DYn49HAw)

Answer (score 10):

> Access to storage is not allowed from this context

As the [documentation says](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#method-StorageArea-setAccessLevel) `session` is only for trusted contexts by default.

**To enable it in the content scripts call [setAccessLevel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#method-StorageArea-setAccessLevel) from such a trusted context** i.e. in the background script or in an extension page like the action popup or options.

```js
chrome.storage.session.setAccessLevel({ accessLevel: 'TRUSTED_AND_UNTRUSTED_CONTEXTS' });
```

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'session')

This error says that the parent of `session` is undefined i.e. `chrome.storage` is undefined, which can only happen in these cases:

- you didn't reload the extension after editing manifest.json
- an [orphaned content script](/a/57471345) tried to access storage after you reloaded or updated the extension
- your code is not a content script, but just a page script e.g. you ran it in a `script` element or injected with `world: 'MAIN'`.

Comment: Do you have any reference where I could understand what UNTRUSTED context actually is? Including why.

Comment: A trusted context means chrome-extension://ID (origin of the extension). An untrusted means anything outside of it, including the content script that run in a web page.

Comment: Wow, thanks for making it explicit. I mean it's pretty obvious yet - to my surprise - nowhere to be found on Chrome docs. Would it be correct to assume that _untrusted_ context would be a website I inject the Context Script too that could _steal_ my data? I would like to understand the technical aspect of it because to my understanding unless it's my own CS, no one else has access to it.

Comment: It can happen theoretically if a web page (or another extension's content script in the web page) finds a way to perform a side channel attack like Meltdown or Spectre.

Comment: So, in my perception, unless my extension is dealing with big crypto wallets (big stakes), the UNTRUSTED is just as safe to use. Let me know if that's wrong.